# Ramifications of React setState directly modifying prevState?

Tags: reactjs

I was looking at some example react code (in the antd docs), and I noticed they have code that is equivalent to:

```
this.setState(prevState => { prevState.name = "NewValue"; return prevState; });
```

This looks a bit naughty, but does it actually break anything? Since it's using the arrow function it's not breaking the ordering of changes being applied even if React batches them up in the background.

Of course setState is intended to expect a partial state so there might be performance side effects there as it might try to apply the whole state to itself.

edit: (in response to @Sulthan)

The actual code is this:

```
handleChange(key, index, value) {
  const { data } = this.state;
  data[index][key].value = value;
  this.setState({ data });
}
```

n.b. data is an array, so its just being copied by reference then mutated.

It's actually completely wrong as its not even using the arrow function to get the latest state.

It comes from the editable table example here: https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: Could you link the example? The arrow function would return the result of assignment and the definitely looks incorrect.

Comment: @Sulthan will add it to the post.

Comment: Your example is not equivalent at all. It means something completely different.

Comment: Yes good point, I was scanning the code yesterday and must have missed that, then when you asked for the example I just grabbed it without looking at it properly :) tks

Comment: ah - just realised in my haste I posted the wrong code from their example. Have updated the question. This is all a bit irrelevant though as the point of the question was more as to the impact of modifying state in the delegate overload of setState. In fact wouldn't it be more efficient to have state managed using a mutable model based on using a delegate?

Comment: Nah, mutable state (the OOP way) is easy to read and write but it's very hard to use it for rendering because you never know what has changed and you always have to rerender everything.  The functional way is to use immutable data structures - the old (immutable) state is converted to a new immutable state. The advantage is that we can use shallow comparison to see what has changed. The performance impact of such an architecture is very significant. You should look into redux architecture to realize the difference.

Comment: I use redux. However with the state, its not shared, its contained within the component, and the ultimate impact of mutating state is that render() is called. I don't think anything smart is happening in terms of avoiding rendering all items into a new ReactElement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example can be also rewritten as:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    prevState.name = "NewValue"
    return "NewValue";
});
```

When a function is passed to the `state` the important thing is not to mutate the passed parameter and return the new state. Your example fails both.

> ...`prevState` is a reference to the previous state. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new state object based on the input from `prevState`...

(from [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

I am not sure whether it was ever possible to use `setState` like in your example but looking into the change log I really doubt it.

Comment: Ah thats a really good point now I reflect on it. I should return prevState, not just return the value of the assignment. Of course this then leads to double assignment.